# Implementing SharedPreferences across multiple Android versions

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

For my application, I have a custom implementation of `SharedPreferences`.

In API level 9, the apply method was added to the `SharedPreferences.Editor` interface.

However, Android 1.6 throws a `VerifyError` if I add that method to my implementation and try to use it.

What is the best way to make this work in a backwards compatible way?

Edit:

I should clarify my conundrum. Before I switched to targeting Gingerbread, my implementation of `SharedPreferences.Editor` did not include the `apply` method. Upon switching the target, it ceased to compile due to that method being missing from my implementation.

Adding an implementation of the method fixed the compile problem, but added a new problem: Android 1.6 will not even load the class, throwing a `VerifyError`. Even if I catch the error, my custom implementation will never load on 1.6.

So far, my best idea has been to make my own interfaces identical to SharedPreferences and SharedPreferences.Editor, and implement those instead. Of course, that's going to require sweeping changes throughout my code, so I'm trying to avoid it if possible.

Comment: catch the VerifyError and `commit`. who runs 1.6 now anyways?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't allow me to actually use my custom implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were willing to drop Android 1.x support, you could just put this in an `if ()` test, akin to:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    editor.apply();
}
else {
    editor.commit();
}
```

If you really need to support back to Android 1.6, though, you will need to isolate the new-API code in a class that only gets loaded on new-API devices, the so-called "conditional class loading" technique.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/CPU-Java/PrefsPersist) demonstrating using this technique for your very problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem is not calling the apply method. My problem is that I have a custom implementation of SharedPreferences, and adding the apply method causes 1.6 to reject my class entirely, even if the apply method is never called.

Comment: @Brigham: You will need two separate custom implementations, one with `apply()` and one without, and only try using the `apply()` one on Gingerbread and higher.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. My only concern with that solution is how to make it compile.

Comment: @Brigham: You have to set your build target to be Gingerbread or higher.